# What happens on Windows 7/8/10 apx. 30 min after start?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, windows-xp

I'v got a curious problem:
On a computer there is only one program running. It acqires camera pictures at a rate of about 20 fps (externally triggered) and saves them as an MJPEG video.

While this works fine most of the time there is one exception:

Every day about 30 minutes after the computer gets turned on something happens that makes the program drop several frames (between 5 and 100, probably related to the current frame rate).

Once that error has occurred once, it works fine again for the rest of the day until it gets shut down in the evening.

The next morning, about 30 minutes after the computer gets turned on, the event occurs again.

It's not related to the time of day but seems to be related to the uptime. If the computer gets turned on later, the event still occurs 30 minutes after that.

This started to happen when we updated the computer (there are actually several of these computers and it happens on all of them) from Windows XP to Windows 7, 8 (8.1) or 10.

I have disabled every service and maintenance task I could think of, but the problem still occurs.

So far, I tried without luck to find anything in the system logs or the performance monitor.

Any idea what the cause could be?

Comment: Disable the Windows Update service, see if that helps.

Comment: Check Task Scheduler.

Comment: No it's not the update service, I checked that.

Comment: No, there is nothing in the task scheduler either.